# How can I create multiple squares in d3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, d3.js, svg

I have an interactive page where I need to make a number of squares appear on the page using d3 with the following counts: 1, 4, 5, 16, 107, 465 and 1745. I don't want to be copy-and-pasting this SVG snippet multiple times.

How can I generate these squares in d3?

`index.html`

```
<svg width="50" height="50">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10" fill="#c62828">
</svg>
```

Comment: Aside from trying to copy and paste squares multiple times, I've taken a look at this example, but I'm unclear on how he is creating the grid of squares: `http://bl.ocks.org/eesur/3fc83ddc4c060e6bd43e`

Comment: Do you want the squares arranged in a grid? In the code you link to, what **specific** part are you confused about?  It's very straight forward `d3` code, so any answer I dream up I'll be regurgitating that example...

Comment: @Mark Not in a grid per se. I just want that many squares to appear on the page in that order: 1, 4, 5, 16, 107, 465 and 1745.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the shortest and "cleanest" `d3` code that meets what I understand from your question.  I've commented it so let me know if something doesn't make sense:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="d3@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    
    <script>
    
    // number of rects
    var data = [1, 4, 5, 16, 107, 465, 1745];
         
    var squareDim = 10, // pixel dimensions of square
        width = 400,
        height = (squareDim * d3.max(data)) + squareDim; // based on the max of my squares, how tall am I going to be
        
    var svg = d3.select('body')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', width)
      .attr('height', height); // create my svg node
    
    var row = 0;
    svg.selectAll('rectGroup')
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append('g') // for each data point create a group
      .selectAll('rect')
      .data(function(d){
        return d3.range(d); // this creates an array of [1, 2, 3 ... N] where N is a datum in your rect data
      }) // this is a sub selection, it allows you to define a sub dataset
      .enter()
      .append('rect')
      .attr('width', squareDim)
      .attr('height', squareDim)
      .attr('x', function(d,i,j){
        return data.indexOf(j.length) * (squareDim + 2);
      }) // determine the x position
      .attr('y', function(d){
        return d * (squareDim + 2);  // and y
      })
      .style('fill', '#c62828');
      
    </script>
    
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm curious why it's taking on that shape? Is it possible to get them into rows of 30 or 100?

Comment: @AndrewNguyen, it's taking that shape because I told it to :).  The "shape" is determined by the `x` and `y` attributes.  `data.indexOf(j.length) * (squareDim + 2);` is essentially saying, which datum am I on, now move over 22 pixels and start the next column.  Yes it possible to arrange them however you want, it's just math.  Give it a go and come back when you have specific troubles.

Comment: I personally think that you shouldn't have answered this question. It's too vague, shows no effort on attempts so far and the specific problem hasn't been highlighted. As you state it from what you managed to understand. I'd advocate flagging the question or at the very least not feeding the help vampires

Comment: @Ian, you are probably right.  I was hoping, though, that a little sample code would enlighten the OP and push them towards working out their own solution.  Instead, I just got more requirements...

Comment: There seems to be a problem when two integers in the array are the same, this is because indexOf finds the first occurrence of a value within the array.